# What is apt and what are its uses?

Tags: apt

In a terminal, if you type `apt-` and press `tab`, you will end up with these suggestions:

[image]

I'd like to see practical examples of how you would use each these commands.

*Note:* I already know how to use a few of these, but would like examples of them all for completeness.

Comment: It might help if you explained why the man pages aren't helping you.

Comment: @CryHavok, I am looking for an answer that shows me how to use it. Not read what it does. I mean the man pages are good. But I would never understand how `apt-mark` works unless I am an expert or I have had an instance where I have used it

Comment: @CryHavok Examples are *always* useful and help even experts get a better understanding of these commands.

Comment: See also this related question: [what is the use of the various apt commands](http://askubuntu.com/questions/183904/what-is-the-use-of-the-various-apt-commands?rq=1).

Comment: Isn't it better to ask for specific examples? This is quite broadly scoped and can turn into a "lists" type of situation. If you have a question about `apt-mark`, ask it by all means.

Comment: @vasa1 I don't see how this is different from http://askubuntu.com/questions/236381/what-is-apparmor The mods even endorsed that one.

Comment: @Seth, What the mod "endorses" is one thing. What I interpret from my reading of the FAQ is another thing. It's quite obvious that the two needn't be the same otherwise I could be a mod myself ;) BTW, I had questioned the broadness of that apparmor question in the meta section. If a question such as "what is apparmor" isn't too broadly scoped I don't know what is.

Comment: I might be echoing somebody else but before you know "how to use it" surely you should know "if you should use it". I'm struggling to find the value in a question with many answers that just rephrase man pages.

Comment: @Seth I like the other question but I'm not keen on this... Mostly because this feel like "What is every command in /usr/bin and what do they do?" AppArmour is a much larger and more mysterious beast.

Comment: @Oli I'm going to attempt an answer.  I'll see if I can get it done quickly.

Comment: @Seth (et al): I may take an axe to this in the morning so please consider this post and comment on it if you care to http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6431/what-makes-a-question-too-broadly-scoped-for-askubuntu/6434#6434

Comment: You will find what you need [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Comment: I really dont understand, what is the problem. Something is not working well?

Answer (score 4):

It is very easy: you type `man apt-cdrom`, for instance, and you get more information and an explanation. You can also navigate the documentation here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/. `man` stands for manual. The command works for a lot of other terminal commands as well.

You usually get a good description and a synopsis. Sometimes you also get practical examples, but that depends on the man page.

1. For `apt-add-repository` it states

   ```
     add-apt-repository is a script which adds an external APT repository to
     either  /etc/apt/sources.list  or a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ or
     removes an already existing repository.
   ```
2. For `apt-get`

   ```
    apt-get is the command-line tool for handling packages, and may be
    considered the user's "back-end" to other tools using the APT library.
    Several "front-end" interfaces exist, such as dselect(1), aptitude(8),
    synaptic(8) and wajig(1).
   ```
3. For `apt-key`

   ```
     apt-key is used to manage the list of keys used by apt to authenticate
     packages. Packages which have been authenticated using these keys will
     be considered trusted.
   ```

For the rest it is **up to you to learn** about these commands in the man pages. The synopsis can hardly get any more practical.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But I know it is time consuming, But Can you show me some practical examples for each one of them ? For the 1st two commands I already know what they do. I was hoping that someone explains the commands with an example. `apt-mark` can be understood if you know how to mark packages which is considered advanced for a user like me

Comment: This just says 'RTFM' to me and does not have the examples the OP is looking for. -1

Comment: @MarkPaskal This is indeed a way of saying RTM [sic]. The manual contains sufficient information for the OP to solve his question. If he wants a tutorial, I personally feel that Ask Ubuntu is not the place. Thanks for you feedback.

Comment: @MarkPaskal, when you hover the mouse cursor over the upvote area, the tooltip that displays has this, in part: *This question shows research effort;* Where is the research effort in this question? That's why I suggested in a comment that OP ask a focused question if a specific problem was encountered. `Apt` is a vast topic and asking to see "some practical examples for each one of them" is not appropriate in my opinion.

Comment: @vasa1 I agree that asking for *any* information on ten separate commands in one question is inappropriate on AU. I do think asking how apt as a whole works (including how it's plethora of command line programs are relevant to me the user) is ok, however. I don't think the question is so much asking just for examples as it's asking 'What are all these and why/when would I use them?